# spring boot DeferredResult onError how to invoke the callback?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Need to perform some asynchronous processing in a Rest service without holding up the server's Http threads .

I think DeferredResult would be a good option.

However when I am trying to ensure my callback on error gets called - am not able to do so .

Here is a naive attempt on my part:

```
@GetMapping("/getErrorResults") 
public DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<?>> getDeferredResultsError(){
    final String METHOD_NAME = "getDeferredResultsError";
    logger.info("START : {}",METHOD_NAME);

    DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<?>> deferredOutput = new DeferredResult<>();

    ForkJoinPool.commonPool().submit(() -> {
        logger.info("processing in separate thread");
        int age = 0;
        try {
            age = age / 0;
        }catch(Exception e) {
            logger.error("we got some error");
            logger.error(e);
            throw e;
        }
        logger.info("after  try catch block");

    });

    deferredOutput.onError((Throwable t) -> {
        logger.error("<<< HERE !!! >>>");
        deferredOutput.setErrorResult(
                  ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                    .body(t.getMessage()));
    });


    logger.info("done");
    return deferredOutput;
}
```

When I call this Rest endpoint from Postman - I can see in server logs the arithmetic exception by zero but dont see the 'onError' getting invoked.

After some time get a response in Postman as follows:

```
{
"timestamp": "2019-07-30T09:57:16.854+0000",
"status": 503,
"error": "Service Unavailable",
"message": "No message available",
"path": "/dfr/getErrorResults"
```

}

So my question is how does the 'onError' get invoked ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the `DeferredResult` object to the asynchronous operation so you could update it in case of success or failure:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/getErrorResults")
public DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<String>> getDeferredResultsError() {
    DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<String>> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<>();
    ForkJoinPool.commonPool().submit(() -> {
        System.out.println("Processing...");
        int age = 0;
        try {
            age = age / 0;
            deferredResult.setResult(ResponseEntity.ok("completed"));
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to process: " + e.getMessage());
            deferredResult.setErrorResult(
                    ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                            .body(e.getMessage()));
        }
    });

    return deferredResult;
}
```

In the code you posted, you returned the `DeferredResult` object without passing it to the asynchronous operation. So after your return it, SpringMVC holds the client connection and wait until the `DeferredResult` object will be assigned with some kind of result. But in your case, the `DeferredResult` is not held by the asynchronous operation and will never updated so you get "Service Unavailable".

[Here](https://github.com/elirandav/springAsyncServlet/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/springAsyncServlet/DeferredResultWithForkjoinController.java) you can find working (light) project example.